# React Native Debug mode throws an error, why is that so?

Tags: react-native

The debug mode was working before, but then after I tried running it again (after 2 days), an error is being thrown saying:

> None of these files exist:   *
>   debugger-ui/debuggerWorker.d9da4ed7(.native|.native.js|.js|.native.json|.json|.native.ts|.ts|.native.tsx|.tsx)

After running react native on debug mode. It also says Native Module cannot be null. How do I fix this? I'm using react native 0.61.5 right now.

Also, I already tried deleting node_modules folder and installing the modules again but it still throws the error. It only throws the error when in debug mode.

Here are the screenshots of the error:

[image]
[image]

Comment: What was done in between causing this issue? or What were you trying to do, end up reaching here? Pretty clueless without more info provided.

Comment: Hi, there was nothing I did in between. I just took a break from developing, and closed that code editor, and simulator, and after I went back to work on it again after 2 days, it already throws this error. I just editted existing javascript files that is not related to any modules or dependencies.

Comment: @VinceGonzales Have you tried deleting your build folder ?

Answer (score 3):

Fixed this issue by deleting my pods folder and Podfile.lock and running `pod install`

Comment: Unfortunately I've done this many many times and it hasn't done me any good